# ssh + screen : how to ?

Tags: ssh, gnu-screen

I am trying to launch a software through ssh :

I can do :

```
ssh -t user@xx.xx.xx.xx 
screen -S datanode -d -m ~/hadoop/bin/hdfs datanode
```

But

```
ssh -t user@xx.xx.xx.xx screen -S datanode -d -m ~/hadoop/bin/hdfs datanode
```

Doesn't work

I tried several options with quotes :

```
ssh -t user@xx.xx.xx.xx screen '-S datanode -d -m ~/hadoop/bin/hdfs datanode'
```

or

```
ssh -t user@xx.xx.xx.xx screen -S datanode -d -m '~/hadoop/bin/hdfs datanode'
```

or

```
ssh -t user@xx.xx.xx.xx screen ' -S datanode -d -m ~/hadoop/bin/hdfs datanode'
```

but I can't find the correct one :-(

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Running remote ssh command with spaces?](https://superuser.com/questions/1142160/running-remote-ssh-command-with-spaces)

Comment: I do not believe the spaces have anything to do with it.  The primary issue is  to tell ssh to go into the background and secondarily, ensure that the `~` is not expanded locally.  Related question: https://superuser.com/questions/1171397/ssh-screen-run-command-and-detach-in-one-go/1171507#1171507

Answer (score 0):

Its better to group the options together

```
ssh -t username@host "screen -dmS 'NAMEofSCREEN' command"
```

You can then reattach with

```
screen -r NAMEofSCREEN
```

Just keep in mind that this won't be a re-attachable screen if `command` exits. For example:

```
ssh -t username@host "screen -dmS 'NAMEofSCREEN' echo | wall"
```

Will give you the `wall` message ...

```
Broadcast message from user@host (pts/15) (Tue Jan 16 12:04:07 2018):
```

**.. but the screen will immediately close after the command ran successful**

Comment: "better to group the options together"?  I would say that is a matter of opinion, and completely irrelevant to the OPs problem.

Comment: Sorry but "-dmS" is kind of standard option-string for screen. It makes it more readable, why use the extra space ? Of course it's not necessary.

Comment: You are right that the extra space is not necessary and arguably more easily readable if you are used to looking at `-dmS NAME`, but it's still not answering the problem raised by the questioner.

Comment: I will update the answer

Answer (score 0):

I see two (potential) problems with your incantation of

```
ssh -t remote screen -S datanode -d -m ~/hadoop/bin/hdfs datanode
```

1. The **client/local** shell (the one executing `ssh`) is the one expanding `~` and replacing with the value of `$HOME`, which may be different from that of the remote server.  Suggest you use either a relative path (e.g. `./hadoop/bin/hdfs`) or a fully-qualified path or quote the remote command with single quotes (e.g. '~/hadoop/bin/hdfs datanode') to prevent expansion on the client.
2. Because the `screen` command is starting a detached instance, but is still a child process of the shell started by ssh, it is terminated when the remote shell exits.

Moreover, since screen creates it's own tty, you don't need the `-t` option to `ssh`.

Try instead using `-f` to tell `ssh` to go into the background just before command execution.  i.e.:

```
ssh -f remote screen -S datanode -d -m ./hadoop/bin/hdfs datanode
```

Equally valid alternative using `nohup`:

```
ssh remote nohup screen -S datanode -d -m ./hadoop/bin/hdfs datanode
```